# table rendered by simple_form with bootstrap just disappear when pdf is rendered with pdfkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

table rendered by simple_form with bootstrap just disappear when pdf is rendered with pdfkit with reference to http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit  and stackoverflow.com/q/12302819/2529182, not able to render a formated pdf e.g not able to hide a link in rendred pdf

```
<link class = "hidden-print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">  <%= link_to "Print Bill", bill_path(@bill, :format => "pdf") %> </link>


below is print.css

@media print {
  .visible-print  { display: inherit !important; }
  .hidden-print   { display: none !important; }
}
```

and all the table rendered by simple_form just disappear when pdf is rendered 
thank you

Answer (score -1):

solved it by using [prawn_pdf](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/)

153 PDFs with Prawn (revised)

Comment: Appreciate coming back to your question, but can you add a little more detail? It might help others having the same problem.

Comment: mabi - thank you for suggesting, found prawn_pdf easier to use, thought my answer said it all and thanks for linking and..